# Why do conditions with %in% ignore missing values?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, recode

I encountered an unexpected output when I used `%in%` in a condition whilst recoding a categorical variable.

When an element of a vector on the left is `NA`, the condition evaluates as `FALSE`, whilst I expected it to be `NA`.

The expected behaviour is the more verbose statement with two `==` conditions separated by an `|`

```r
dt <- data.frame(colour = c("red", "orange", "blue", NA))

# Expected
dt$is_warm1 <- ifelse(dt$colour == "red" | dt$colour == "orange", TRUE, FALSE)

# Unexpected
dt$is_warm2 <- ifelse(dt$colour %in% c("red", "orange"), TRUE, FALSE)

dt
```

```r
#>   colour is_warm1 is_warm2
#> 1    red     TRUE     TRUE
#> 2 orange     TRUE     TRUE
#> 3   blue    FALSE    FALSE
#> 4   <NA>       NA    FALSE
```

This is quite unhelpful when recoding categorical variables because it silently fills missing values. Why does this happen, and are there any alternatives that don't involve listing all the `==` conditions? (Imagine that `colour` contains thirty possible levels).

Comment: This behaviour is  well explained / justified in the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%in%` checks to see if `NA` is in the list. Consider these two scenarios

```
NA %in% 1:3
# [1] FALSE
NA %in% c(1:3, NA)
# [1] TRUE
```

This allows you to check of NA is in the vector or not.

If you want to preserve NA values, you could write your own alternative

```
`%nain%` <- function(val, list) {
  ifelse(is.na(val), NA, val %in% list)
}
```

And then you can use

```
dt$is_warm3 <- dt$colour %nain% c("red", "orange")
```

Answer (score 5):

`a %in% b` is just shorthand for `match(a, b, nomatch = 0) > 0` (check the source code for `%in%` to satisfy yourself that this is the case).

You can get your expected result by removing the `nomatch = 0` argument:

```r
match(dt$colour, c("red", "orange")) > 0
#> [1] TRUE TRUE   NA   NA
```

Which of course doesn't require the `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some info from the help documentation ?`%in%`

So you can see in the last line `%in%` never returns NA so that is why it returns `FALSE` and not `NA`. It is checking for missing values as @MrFlick mentioned in his answer

> Exactly what matches what is to some extent a matter of definition.
> For all types, NA matches NA and no other value. For real and complex
> values, NaN values are regarded as matching any other NaN value, but
> not matching NA, where for complex x, real and imaginary parts must
> match both (unless containing at least one NA).
>
> Character strings will be compared as byte sequences if any input is
> marked as "bytes", and otherwise are regarded as equal if they are in
> different encodings but would agree when translated to UTF-8 (see
> Encoding).
>
> That %in% never returns NA makes it particularly useful in if
> conditions.